# While doing Monkeytalk setup in xcode for iOS app i faced this issue and i am stuck here

Tags: monkeytalk

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::string::compare(std::string const&) const", referenced from:
      bool std::operator==<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::allocator<char>::allocator()", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::allocator<char>::~allocator()", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::string::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      MTwebdriver::MTatoms::asString(char const* const*) in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAtom:withArgs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      MTwebdriver::MTatoms::asString(char const* const*) in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeScript:withArgs:isFinding:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeMonkeyTalkJs:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
      -[MTHTTPVirtualDirectory(ExecuteScript) executeAsyncJsFunction:withArgs:withTimeout:] in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
  "std::string::operator+=(char const*)", referenced from:
      MTwebdriver::MTatoms::asString(char const* const*) in libMonkeyTalk-2.0.10.a(MTHTTPVirtualDirectory+ExecuteScript.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the library `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` in order to build your app with the *MonkeyTalk Agent*.